# Location of default Lubuntu desktop images

Tags: 13.10, lubuntu, desktop-background

I changed my Lubuntu (13.10)'s default desktop background image to an original image. However, I want to go back to the default image, but I can't find where the image is on my computer- this means I can't choose it as a background.

Where is the location of the default Lubuntu desktop image?

Comment: Try to look into `/usr/share/backgrounds`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Lubuntu you can find default wallpapers at `/usr/share/lubuntu/wallpapers`.

Comment: This answer is still valid for Lubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

For **Lubuntu 16.04 xenial** panel images it's `/usr/share/lxpanel/images`

Answer (score 1):

For Lubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (Bionic Beaver, LXDE desktop), as per @Stormvirux answer, desktop images are still stored in /usr/share/lubuntu/wallpapers